# Angular JS directive for automatically insert slashes '/' in date fields. for Example MM/DD/yyyy

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to add functionality to input date fields so as when the users enters in digits, slashes "/" get automatically added its in Jquery but I need in Angular JS directive.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply am new to angularjs I referred this link http://jsfiddle.net/4K2Dj/3/ but its not auto filled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found easy solution for my question as per my requirement I hope it will be help full for others.
If you are using anguler-dialog.js you can use directive as `<input type="text" ng-model="Modelname" ui-mask="99/99/999" ui-mask-placeholder>`

Answer (score 3):

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('appCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
       $scope.change = function(e) {
        var numChars = $scope.date.length;
    if(numChars === 2 || numChars === 5){
     var thisVal = $scope.date;
     thisVal += '/';
     $scope.date = thisVal;
    }
        };
    }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="appCtrl">
        <h4>Minimum date</h4>
        <input minlength="0"  maxlength="10" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" id="date" ng-change="change()" ng-model="date">
     </div>
```

Working example. Please try it

Comment: Hi Ayush thanks for your reply 
Could you please help me to do like this URL:  jsfiddle.net/ChrisCoray/hLkjhsce

Comment: can you please create a fiddle so I can edit your code

Answer (score 1):

You can use this directive:

https://github.com/g00fy-/angular-datepicker

Specify the **format** like this:

```
<input date-time format="yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm">
```

Comment: Could you please help me to do like this URL: https://jsfiddle.net/ChrisCoray/hLkjhsce/

Answer (score 1):

The previous answers didn't quite fit what I needed so I wrote this directive to specifically address dates in mm/dd/yyyy format and to automatically add slashes if appropriate.

```
app.directive('addDobSlashes', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attr, ctrl) {

      var isDelete = false;
      element.keydown(function(e) {
        isDelete = e.keyCode === 8; // if we hit delete
      });
      // store regex patterns
      var mmRegEx = /^(0?[23456789]|01|10|12)$/;
      var mmDDRegEx = /^(0?[23456789]|01|10|12|1)[\/.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$/;

      function inputValue(val) {
        if (isDelete) {
          return val;
        }

        if (val) {
          //first only allow digits and slashes
          val = val.replace(/[^0-9\/]/g, '');

          // prevent duplicate
          if (val[val.length - 1] === '/' && val.length - 2 >= 0 && val[val.length - 2] === '/') {
            val = val.slice(0, -1);
          }
          // test against or mm or mm/dd regex patterns
          // automatically add slashes
          if (mmRegEx.test(val)) {
            val += '/';
          } else if (mmDDRegEx.test(val)) {
            val += '/';
          }
          ctrl.$setViewValue(val);
          ctrl.$render();
          return val;
        } else {
          return undefined;
        }
      }
      ctrl.$parsers.push(inputValue);
    }
  };
});
```